# How can I change ImageButton through another activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How can I change **ImageButton** through another activity? 
example:
I have imageButton in MainActivity.class and when I click on button in another activity changes ImageButton in the MainActivity.class

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a Local Broadcast Receiver in the Activity from where you can access the ImageButton. This receiver will be capable of hearing for a message and do something that you specify in response.

So, when you want to change the ImageButton you can send a message from the other Activity that will be received by the first one and will change the ImageButton. This message will be in an Intent form and can contain many extras.

**EDIT**

**In your Activity #1 (The one who controls the ImageButton)**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   ...
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mLocalBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("broadcastName"));
}

private BroadcastReceiver mLocalBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //MODIFY YOUR IMAGE BUTTON HERE

    }
};
```

**In your Activity #2 (The broadcast sender)**

*Call sendLocalBroadcast()* in any part of this Activity when you want to send the message *to update the ImageButton*. You can add many parameters as you want, of course.

```
private void sendLocalBroadcast() {
        Intent intent = new Intent("broadcastName");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```